# Why intensity of light reaching the sensor or film with a particular lens directly proportional to $\frac{D^2}{f^2}$?

Tags: geometric-optics

The following is quoted from my book:

"The intensity of light reaching the sensor or film is proportional to the area viewed by the camera lens and to the effective area of the lens. The size of the area that the lens "sees" is proportional to the square of the angle of view of the lens, and so is roughly proportional to $\frac{1}{f^2}$. The effective area of the lens is controlled by means of an adjustable lens aperture, or diaphragm, a nearly circular hole with variable diameter $D$; hence the effective area is propor tional to $D^2$. Putting these factors together, we see that the intensity of light reaching the sensor or film with a particular lens is proportional to $\frac{D^2}{f^2}$."

My question is how did they conclude that the area that the lens "sees" is roughly proportional to the square of angle of view of the lens and $\frac{1}{f^2}$ and how is the effective area proportional to $D^2$? Ultimately, my question is how is the intensity of light proportional to $\frac{D^2}{f^2}$? Can someone please explain? I did not understand what the paragraph explained. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The first term, proportional to $D^2$, is rather simple: The larger your lens aperture, i.e. the larger the area that collects light, the more photons you get.

The second term is a bit misleading. Actually, the smaller the focal length $f$, the larger the angle of view $\alpha$ that the camera sees, both in the horizontal and vertical:
$$
\alpha = 2 \cdot \arctan \left(\frac{d}{2 f} \right)
$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view). $d$ is either the width or height of your camera chip, $\alpha$ the corresponding angle (so there is $\alpha_w$ and $\alpha_h$).

The width of the observed scene is proportional to $\tan(\alpha_w)$, the height is proportional to $\tan(\alpha_h)$. Thus according to the equation above you see that both width and height are proportional to $\frac{1}{f}$. The total amount of photons your camera collects is of course proportional to the image area, therefore to the product of width and height and thus proportional to $\frac{1}{f^2}$.

Comment: but how is the area that the lens "sees" directly proportional to the 'square' of the angle of view of the lens? Why 'square'? From where did this 'square' come from?

Comment: @Ripan Baruah Because the area that the solid angle $\Omega$ sees in the distance $r$ is $A = \Omega \cdot r^2$, <https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle>. And the solid angle is proportional to $\frac{1}{f^2}$ as explained above.

Comment: Tucker, but if $A = Ωr^{2}$ then, $A\proptoΩ$. So, the area that the lens "sees" should be directly proportional to just the angle of view of the lens (as $A\proptoΩ$) and not the 'square' of the angle of view of the lens (as $A\proptoΩ$ and not $A\proptoΩ^2$), right?

Comment: @Ripan Buruah Yes, the area that the lens sees is directly proportional to the solid  angle, and that angle is proportional to $\frac{1}{f^2}$.

Comment: Tucker, then why is it written that the area that the lens "sees" is directly proportional to the square of the angle of view of the lens? It clearly is directly proportional to just the angle of view of the lens (I proved it above) and NOT the 'square' of the angle of view of the lens. Does this mean that my book is wrong?

Comment: @Ripan Baruah You have an $\alpha$ for the horizontal angle, and one for the vertical. You need to multiply horizontal and vertical to get the solid angle or the observed area. For simplicity I assumed both angles to be the same, which is the reason for the square. I fear that was confusing you - sorry...

Comment: I don't think that multiplying the horizontal angle and the vertical angle gives us the solid angle. Can you prove it?

Comment: It is of course an approximation, you could google for the solid angle of a pyramid, which would be the precise angle of the scene. However, you are loosing track of your initial question, you asked why the number of photons is proportional to $\frac{1}{f^2}$. And the answer is that the opening angle in both the vertical and horizontal and thus the width and the height of the observed scene is each proportional to the $\frac{1}{f}$.

Comment: Tucker, can you please provide the proof of why multiplying the horizontal angle and the vertical angle gives the solid angle? I cannot find it. Please help.

Comment: As mentioned, it's an approximation, to be precise you need to integrate over spherical coordinates. Anyways, maybe you better see the point neglecting solid angles and go with areas. Imagine you have an image of width $w$, height $h$ and area $A$ in distance $r$. Then $A = w \cdot h$, $w = 2 r \cdot tan(0.5 \alpha_w)$, $h = 2 r \cdot tan(0.5 \alpha_h)$. $\alpha$ you find in my answer above. (BTW You see, two angles, and for small angles $tan(\alpha) \approx \alpha$)

Comment: Tucker, so according to your calculations $A=r^{2}(α_{w}α_{h})$. Now clearly, $α_{w}≠α_{h}$. So, $A \propto α_{w}α_{h}$ which is NOT the square of the angle of view of the lens as $α_{w}≠α_{h}$. So, we don't get $A\propto α^2$. How do we get $A\propto α^2$?

Comment: As mentioned some comments up, you get the square of course only when width and height are the same (for simplicity assumed).

Comment: Tucker, we are taking too many assumptions, aren't we? Doesn't it lead to large deviation from the actual results?

Comment: Ripan, you asked why the proportional to square of 1/f term and I explained this at length. I edited my answer above to make things more clear. Additional remark: In general, simplifications are welcome if you are interested in understanding the underlying principle (which I think is your aim here). They are not ok, if you want to calculate sone quantity precisely.

Comment: "As mentioned, it's an approximation, to be precise you need to integrate over spherical coordinates." @Charles Tucker, could you provide the proof which has the integral involved? Don't worry, I know calculus.

Comment: You can just look at wikipedia for solid angle <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle>. In the section "Solid angles for common objects" (in that link) are a lot examples. However, for your initially posted question we are running out of scope. If you want to continue, let's do it in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about a camera, it's more appropriate to talk about the illumination of an image which translates to the amount of light per unit area of the image. The dependence on D$^2$ is straightforward as that is proportional to the area of the lens aperture.

The magnification due to the camera lens is given approximately by the image distance divided by the object distance. For a far away object, the image distance is approximately equal to f. So the linear extent of the image depends on f and the area of the image depends on f$^2$. The smaller the area, the more concentrated is the light on the image.

So the image brightness depends, for a distant object, on D$^2$/f$^2$. This is just the inverse of the f/number and as we know the smaller the f/number (hence the larger D$^2$/f$^2$), the brighter the image.